# is Parquet predicate pushdown works on S3 using Spark non EMR?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, parquet

Just wondering if Parquet predicate pushdown also works on S3, not only HDFS. Specifically if we use Spark (non EMR).

Further explanation might be helpful since it might involve understanding on distributed file system.

Comment: This aws release guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3select.html  says `S3 select` does pushdown filtering only on csv, json and gzip files. It does not mention parquet files. I was looking around if snappy parquet is supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Filter pushdown does not depend on the underlying file system. It only depends on the `spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown` and the type of filter (not all filters can be pushed down).

See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetFileFormat.scala#L313 for the pushdown logic.

Comment: According to Emily Curtin at Spark Summit, it does depend on the "file system" (in this case object store), as S3 doesn't support random access. https://youtu.be/_0Wpwj_gvzg?t=1307

Comment: Thanks! And another upvoted answer also says I'm wrong. I looked up the code again in Spark 2.2.0 and it still does not seem to depend on the file system. But it could somehow indirectly depend on it.

Comment: But S3 does have random access: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html#ExampleGetRangeRequestHeaders

And Hortonworks talks about filter pushdown on S3: https://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-spark/index.html#reading-orc-and-parquet-datasets

Comment: Interesting. Maybe S3 support for random access was added after the talk?

Comment: I think it's been there for a while https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436057/s3-how-to-do-a-partial-read-seek-without-downloading-the-complete-file

Answer (score 16):

I was wondering this myself so I just tested it out. We use **EMR clusters** and **Spark 1.6.1** .

- I generated some dummy data in Spark and saved it as a parquet file locally as well as on S3.
- I created multiple Spark jobs with different kind of filters and column selections. I ran these tests once for the local file and once for the S3 file.
- I then used the Spark History Server to see how much data each job had as input.

Results:

- For the local parquet file: The results showed that the column selection and filters were pushed down to the read as the input size was reduced when the job contained filters or column selection.
- **For the S3 parquet file:** The input size was always the same as the Spark job that processed all of the data. **None of the filters or column selections were pushed down to the read.** The parquet file was always completely loaded from S3. Even though the query plan (.queryExecution.executedPlan) showed that the filters were pushed down.

I will add more details about the tests and results when I have time.

Comment: Looking at another question recently, it looks as though not much has improved.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the keys I'd recommend for s3a work

```
spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown true
spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema false
spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata false

spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown true
spark.sql.orc.splits.include.file.footer true
spark.sql.orc.cache.stripe.details.size 10000

spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning true
```

For committing the work. use the S3A "zero rename committer" (hadoop 3.1+) or the EMR equivalent. The original FileOutputCommitters are slow and unsafe

Comment: What's the best way to set these values? I use Spark in an AWS EMR Cluster and I have set these (summary-metadata and algorithm version) in my Scala spark script. And I have been using filterPushdown and mergeSchema only as options for Parquet read/write. But I want to somehow get rid of the _$folder$ files which are written to S3.

Comment: EMR? beyond my knowledge, I'm afraid.

Comment: EMR is Elastic MapReduce service on AWS. But I'm not even sure if this question is relevant. I haven't used it for years now and your reply wasn't the fastest either :D

Comment: Sorry, I meant "I don't know anything about EMR internals and especially its closed source connector to s3". And yeah, not that timely. That was from spark.defaults conf file BTW

Answer (score 1):

Recently I tried this with Spark 2.4 and seems like Pushdown predicate works with s3.

This is the spark sql query:

```
explain select * from default.my_table where month = '2009-04' and site = 'http://jdnews.com/sports/game_1997_jdnsports__article.html/play_rain.html' limit 100;
```

And here is the part of output:

```
PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(month#6), (month#6 = 2009-04)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(site), EqualTo(site,http://jdnews.com/sports/game_1997_jdnsports__article.html/play_ra...
```

Which clearly stats that PushedFilters is not empty.

**Note:** The used table was created on top of AWS S3

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses the HDFS parquet & s3 libraries so the same logic works.
(and in spark 1.6 they've added even a faster shortcut for flat schema parquet files)