# Splitting the initial file on AWS Step function parallel tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I want to run a parallel task with a step function on a really big file.

is there a way to make the lambdas that will be processing the big file receive a different part of the file? Instead of them all getting the same big file?

Comment: all plain text files? For example,  you can split it and handle 100 lines only each time.

Comment: It's a csv file, how do I pass the seperate inputs to each lambda to process in parallel?

Comment: You will need either to split the file and create multiple smaller files on S3 or  do partial reads from S3 in each Lambda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436057/s3-how-to-do-a-partial-read-seek-without-downloading-the-complete-file

Comment: Thanks blueCat. If you write that up, I will accept as the answer.