# Encoding error while reading a csv file from S3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, amazon-s3

I'm getting this error while trying to parse through a csv file. File is being fetched from a S3 bucket and being processed in chunks/iterations. Added the code snippet as well. I have tried setting the encoding to utf-8 and also set it to unicode escape. They both did not work. I'm currently trying out latin-1. Just wanted to sure if my approach is correct towards this problem.

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 43: invalid start byte**

```
csv_iterator = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], iterator=True, chunksize=10000,low_memory=False,
                           encoding="latin-1")
```

Comment: Yes your approach is correct because it looks like an encoding problem. However, rather than trying random encodings, maybe you should download the file locally and check its encoding?

Comment: It's a huge file to sift through which is why I'm just running the code to validate if it works. What other encoding do you think I should try if this doesn't work?

Comment: Try partially reading your file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36436057/15239951.