# how to download portion of video which was uploaded into AWS s3 bucket, though Nodejs SDKs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I have uploaded a 1GB .mp4 file to an AWS S3 bucket. Using the AWS-SDK provided by the npm package, I am able to download the entire video. However, I have a specific requirement to generate a thumbnail at the 6-second mark of the video. Currently, I download the entire 1GB video to my local machine and then generate the thumbnail at the desired duration.

To optimize server resources and reduce disk load, I plan to download only the first 10 seconds of the video, which should be approximately 10MB or less in size. By doing so, I can significantly reduce download time and server load while still fulfilling my requirement of generating the thumbnail at the 6-second mark. Therefore, instead of downloading the entire 1GB video, I aim to download only the 10MB segment corresponding to the first 10 seconds of the video.

I am using nodejs, expressJS, as backed Technologies.

`

```
`async function downloadS3FileToLocalDirAndReturnPath(videoKey) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            AWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId: config.AWS.KEYS.accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: config.AWS.KEYS.secretAccessKey,
                region: config.AWS.KEYS.region,
                httpOptions: config.AWS.KEYS.httpOptions
            });
            const s3 = new AWS.S3();

            // Specify the local file path where you want to save the downloaded video
            const localFilePath = `${os.tmpdir()}/${Date.now()}_sre.mp4`;

            // Configure the parameters for the S3 getObject operation
            const params = {
                Bucket: config.AWS.S3_BUCKET,
                Key: videoKey
            };

            const result = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
            const fileContent = result.Body;
            fs.writeFileSync(localFilePath, fileContent);
            resolve(localFilePath);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}`
```

this code was working fine to  download the whole video , but i need to download only first 10 seconds duration

[S3: How to do a partial read / seek without downloading the complete file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436057/s3-how-to-do-a-partial-read-seek-without-downloading-the-complete-file)

I tried this ,before posting this question with above post, video was downloading , it was not playing , by throwing this error , the file contains no playable streams

```
async function generateThumbnails(videoKey) {

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const params = {
    Bucket: KEYS.bucket,
    Key: videoKey, // Specify the key of the video file in S3
    Range: `bytes=0-${1024 * 800}`, // Specify the range of bytes you want to retrieve
};

const file = fs.createWriteStream(`/tmp/${Date.now()}_rama.mp4`);

const s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

s3Stream.pipe(file);

s3Stream.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("Error Occured while File downloading!! ");
});

s3Stream.on("finish", () => {
    console.log("File downloaded Successfully ");
});
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436057/s3-how-to-do-a-partial-read-seek-without-downloading-the-complete-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [S3: How to do a partial read / seek without downloading the complete file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436057/s3-how-to-do-a-partial-read-seek-without-downloading-the-complete-file)

Comment: I tried this ,before posting this question, video was downloading , it was not playing , by throwing this error , the file contains no playable streams

Comment: well, that's the task. you need to understand the mp4 format and download correct part. MP4 is a container so you probably need a bit more data to make it happen, still not the whole file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP4_file_format

Comment: depending on your requirements it may make more sense to use a service like https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/ I never used it, just quickly googled